# Can't make payment in Paypal sandbox but works fine in my live account

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I have set up a custom cart to make payments through Paypal Payments Standard. but I I have not got the return flow and IPN flow completed and tested yet as I can't get this to run in sandbox. I can get it to run on my live Paypal account but that means making live payments to get to the return flows.

I am using encrypted form data and the sandbox related certs/keys/cert_id, url, test business account, return paths

and seem to be passing the decryption process. (it fails decryption if I enter wrong values).

I am also logged into my developer account in another tab.

But I get the following screen:

[image: Screenshot of Paypal result]

Cookies are not the issue as I have used a different browser that has never visited either site before.

Why will this process payments on my live account and not my sandbox account?

Here is my data:

```
item_name_1 => Test product 1
amount_1 => 0.01
item_number_1 => T-1
quantity_1 => 1
item_name_2 => Test Product 2
amount_2 => 100.00
item_number_2 => AC-H
quantity_2 => 1
tax_2 => 10
invoice => 001
cmd => _cart
return => http://my site/confirm_payment.php
cancel_return => http://my site/cart.php?payment=cancelled
upload => 1
business => **sandbox receiving business account**
cert_id => **sandbox cert_id***
```

Here is the form:

```
<form id="paypal_form" method="post" action=" https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value=" -----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIIZQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIIVjCCCFICAQAxggE6MIIBNgIBADCBnjCBmDELMAkG
*******************************************************
MaLf05hTBRkTdFPzrnrslM72Ihz6C2NNGn8Ss3lcJ6vxi3dKvyLeUWc=
-----END PKCS7-----">
    <input type="submit" name="paypal" value="Pay via Paypal">
</form>So why would this work in my live account and not the sandbox?
```